# How to paste Chinese/Unicode characters to Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, encoding, unicode

I'm trying to paste these Chinese letters: 你好世界 to my Terminal, but instead I've got "^L" or some other weird characters.

The same happens for other unicode characters (such as £āēīōūśṣṭēīōū) when pasting or pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd> for á, <kbd>e</kbd> for é, <kbd>i</kbd> for í and similar, then I've got C!C)C- instead.

In Terminal Settings, I've got Character encoding set to Unicode (UTF-8) (`Preferences/Settings/Profiles/Advanced`) and in Encodings tab I've UTF-8 enabled.

I've `LANG=C`, however setting it to `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` doesn't help.

However it works when I run echo:

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
```

My Terminal settings are:

[image: Terminal Settings on OSX]

I'm using Terminal v2.4 on OS X Mavericks (10.9.5). My shell is bash.

How I can configure Terminal to support Unicode characters?

Comment: works fine at default settings for me. I'm no terminal guru so I've never changed any settings in there. I can't find that Emulation pane though, where is it? EDIT...What OS are you on, I found the prefs but no Emulation header.

Comment: I'm on OS X Mavericks (10.9.5). Terminal v2.4.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite - essentially, the same prefs settings [other than Bell, which is unlikely to be the kicker] I also have VT100 checked; I'm guessing that ain't it either.

Comment: @Tetsujin Emulation pane is in Preferences->Settings. choose your Profiles and Advanced tag.

Comment: Yup - I found it, it just doesn't say Emulation, it says Input on Yosemite - threw me for a minute